# Electrostatic energy of any charge distribution sum up to charge Q should be equal over the whole space?

Tags: electromagnetism

Intuitively I think that even if you have two different charge distribution but their charges are sum up to the same charge Q, their electrostatic energies over the whole space should be same (Maybe one can support this idea by conservation of energy because we deal with static case so $\vec E$ field is conservative).

However if I took a single charge $Q$ at a origin and I took a uniform non conductor sphere radius $R$ at the origin. Their(single charge and sphere) $\vec E$ field are the same outside the sphere but inside the $R$ spherical region single charge is always bigger than sphere at any coordinate. Hence Energies of sphere and single charge are not equal even their charges are equal. Why is it intiutively hard to understand? I didnot understand.

Comment: Your intuition about this is wrong. The field energy of two equal charges, say each $Q/2$, varies with their separation.

Comment: you are right, and in my case single charge Q has more energy because to uniformly stretch the single charge over a solid sphere radius R you dont have to do work even more energy decreases

Comment: @G.Smith Is there any mathematics proof of the phenomenon you described, thank you